# генерация больших XML

Tags: php, xml

Генерирую  xml для различных сервисов . В базе данные добавляются с каждым днем и на данный момент сам скрипт тратит на генерацию 40 - 50 тыс записей более 1.3 гб памяти.

Основную  часть памяти забирает выборка из базы всех записей (в выборке только нужные колонки указаны).

Подскажите, как выходить в данном случае ? полагаю, что нужно выборку из базы как-то грамотнее сделать , возможно как-то ее разделять или лимитировать ?

Скрипт на данный момент генерируется раз в час-два

Comment: дак и разделите выборку, в чем проблема то? зы: с помощью чего пишите xml то? и что за субд? она сама не умеет формировать XML ?

Answer (score 0):

Данные из БД следует выбирать в цикле чанками, например по 100 записей раз за разом. 
Оптимальное количество записей в чанке зависит от сложности запроса, самих данных и железа. Избегайте `offset` для выборки, он ресурсоёмок.

В этом же цикле поточно записывать файл, в данном случае стандартный [XMLWriter](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlwriter.php) отлично подойдёт.

Если файлов много, а исходят они из одних данных, то можно открыть сразу несколько файлов и фильтровать/модифицировать выгрузку под нужды разных сервисов в один проход.